# Accessing Value in Dictionary thru Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

In the Python file that controls the Jinja template I create a dictionary:

```
disp_list = {}
for comp in requested_workspace.components:
    if comp.show_on_report_list:
        disp_list[comp.label] = {}
        disp_list[comp.label]['descrip'] = comp.description
```

In the Jinja template I want to display values from the dictionary:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
        {% for listing in disp_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ listing }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ listing['descrip'] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

{{ listing }} displays but {{ listing['descrip'] }} won't display.  Am I accessing the 2nd value incorrectly?

Comment: can you show us the dict data and the flask code as well?

Comment: Whats the display for: {{ listing }} and {{ listing.descrip }}?

Comment: {{listing}} becomes <td>Bokeh Example</td> and {{listing.descrip}} is <td></td>.  The 2nd one is supposed to display a text string.

Answer (score 0):

The Python file controlling the Jinja template was fine. I didn't change it. The Jinja template (HTML file) was where the change was needed.

```
{% for item_name, values in disp_list.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ item_name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ values['descrip'] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Using .items() allows me to use tuple explosion and get 2 values out of the dictionary.